# Chamar um método através de linhas do datatable

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Dado o meu datatable abaixo:

```
<p:dataTable id="tabela" var="linha" value="#{naturemb.lista}" paginator="true" rows="10" rendered="#{not empty naturemb.lista}" >
                    <p:column styleClass="botoesGrid">
                    <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-pencil" action="#{naturemb.editar(linha.id)}" process="@this" update="cadastro,pesquisa" ajax="false"/>
                    <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-trash" action="#{naturemb.excluir(linha)}" ajax="true" process="@this">
                    <p:confirm header="#{msg['cabecalho.apagar.registro']}" message="#{msg['apagar.registro']}" icon="ui-icon-alert"/>
                    </p:commandButton>
                    <p:confirmDialog global="true" showEffect="exploud" hideEffect="fade">
                        <p:commandButton value="Sim" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check"/>
                        <p:commandButton value="Não" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="ui-icon-close" />
                    </p:confirmDialog>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="#{msg['nome']}" sortBy="#{linha.nome}" style="width:12%;">
                        <h:outputText value="#{linha.nome}" />
                    </p:column>
```

Estou criando um método para que se dentro das linhas haja algumas palavras específicas, as mesmas terão formatação diferente. Como chamo o método que fará esta verificação no `<h:outputText` ? Ou não seria nele que chamo o método?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para vários estilos você poderia criar um método no bean que retorna o styleClass de acordo com o valor passado:

```
.base{
    background-image: none !important;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 100%!imporant;
    height: 100%!imporant;
}
.base .atack{
    color: blue !important;
}
.base .foo{
    color: yellow !important;
}
.base .bar{
    color: red !important;
}
```

e no bean

```
private static final String ATACK = "atack";
  private static final String FOO = "foo";
  private static final String BAR = "bar";    
  public String getStyle(String val){         
      if(val.toLowerCase().contains(ATACK))
          return ATACK;       
      else if(val.toLowerCase().contains(FOO))
          return FOO;         
      else if(val.toLowerCase().contains(BAR))
          return BAR;         
      return "";
  }
```

no xhtml

```
<p:column **styleClass="base"**>
   < h:outputText value="#{var.nome}" styleClass="#{seuBean.getStyle(var.nome)}"/>
</p:column>
```

Comment: Show, vou testar e te informo se deu certo. Mas o que significam o foo e o bar?

Comment: qualquer outra variável que vc quer informar, como se fosse x e y na matemática, mas note que a verificação é feita e retornada com base na subclasse do css, por exemplo: verifica se o valor contem atack e retorna o atack que por sua vez é uma subclasse do css. Assim se vc quer incluir digamos "defesa" teria que adicionar a subclasse .base .defesa{
    color: black !important;
} e no beam incluir a verificação da mesma private 1º criar o atributo static final String DEFESA = "defesa"; 2º adicionar o else if para defesa.

Comment: Show, devo testar ainda hoje e te falo. Muito obrigado.

Comment: Show, funcionou, muito obrigado.